# How could I bulk update mongoDB with a array with different value

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

How could I bulk update mongoDB with a array.

I need to update about dozens of thosuands of documents at a time.

Can I update in bulk with mongoid ?

I tried the following method,

But it didn't work.

I got this error `NoMethodError: undefined method`update' for #`

## sample code

```
tickets = [100,000 items]

updated_flights = []
tickets.each do |tik|
  @flight = Flight.find_or_create_by(id: id, from: tik.from, to: tik.to)
  @flight = DO_SOMETHING
  updated_flights << @flight
end
Flight.collection.update(updated_flights)
```

> Each document has different values to be updated

## Notice

I want fetch record by `Flight.find_or_create_by ...`,

and change its value then push into array.

Finally update the array of objects at a time.

Comment: This is a bit vague really. What sort of information do you want to update? Where is the inforamation to update coming from? Is it a list you are processing or static values? You say to want t find or create documents. so where are the id values coming from? Are the also in that list or another list. You need to clearly explain what you want to do if you expect to get the correct answer to what you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can use multi keyword in your update query statement to update multiple documents.

example: For a specific flight departure time has been changed. So you want to change it in tickets also. you can use like this:

```
tickets.update( { "id" : "flight_id_to_be_update" }, { "$set" : { "departureTime" : "16:00" } }, { "multi" : true } });
```

Comment: i didn't understand your suggetion. thats say i have an array of objects to be updated into DB, `[ARRAY of object]` . how to convert it into your solution. because it seems you showed only one documents not multiple

Comment: I think you were talking about this `Band.where(name: "Photek").update_all(label: "Mute")` , but i'm not going to do that way. because every document has different value to set

Comment: Yes, you are right. I told you about multiple doc update with same type value

Comment: sorry~~ i made you misundertand my meaning :)

Comment: Have you checked this : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/

Comment: it still seems  update the same value for multiple documents. `var bulk = db.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find( { status: "D" } ).update( { $set: { status: "I", points: "0" } } );
bulk.find( { item: null } ).update( { $set: { item: "TBD" } } );`